# Subsetting dataframe produces 0 rows

Tags: r

I'm working with a matrix of 7634x589. I'm trying to subset my data into two lists:

- a random samples of 5344 rows (70% of the data), and
- the rest of the data (2290 rows [30% of the data])

Here's what I'm doing:

```
> dim(mydata)
[1] 7634  589
> trainingset <- mydata[sample(1:nrow(mydata), 5344),]
> dim(trainingset)
[1] 5344  589
```

This is all looking perfect up until this:

```
> testingset <- mydata[!trainingset]
> dim(testingset)
NULL
```

I'm trying to get the testingset to include everything but the training set. It should have dimensions of 2290x589. Apparently I'm doing something wrong. Can someone help me figure it out? I REALLY appreciate the help, fellas.

---

After taking suggestions from the commenters, I encountered this issue:

```
> dim(mydata)
[1] 7634  589
> id <- sample(1:nrow(mydata), 5344)
> trainingset <- mydata[id, ]
> dim(trainingset)
[1] 5344  589
> testingset <- mydata[!id, ]
> dim(testingset)
[1]   0 589
```

Can't figure out why `mydata[!id, ]` would return 0 rows. Thanks for bearing with me, I'm quite new to this. :(

Comment: Your title is misleading. The `sample()` seems to be working fine. The problem is the `testingset <- mydata[!trainingset]` line. I'm not sure why you think you can subset a data.frame using another data.frame because that's not valid. The first time you did the proper `[row,col]` subsetting of `mydata`. I think you should try that again.

Comment: You're removing all the columns.

Comment: Thank you so much user20650, that's the lesson I needed!

Comment: MrFlick, thanks for the lesson in how to properly title my questions, I'll keep that in mind from now on! y'all are the best.

Comment: I spoke too soon, I have a follow issue which I updated above. Any help would be great!

Comment: Sorry, meant `mydata[-id, ]`

Comment: As a debugging strategy, always remember you can run tiny pieces of R code... probably just running `!id` and seeing what you get would help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, the suggestion of using `mydata[-id, ]` instead of `mydata[!id, ]` worked. Thanks fellas!

Answer (score 0):

`testingset` is just a vector.  It has no `dim`.  You can verify this using

```
typeof(testingset)
```

The dim of a vector is NULL.